# 100% height to parent with no height

Tags: html, css, height, parent

Yeah i have been working width some height ajustments but can't seem to get it working propperly, using html5 & css3.

---

### HTML

```
 1. <section>
 2.    <article>
 3.       Article 1
 4.    </article>
 5.    <article>
 6.       Article 2
 7.    </article>
 8.    <article>
 9.       Article 3
 10.   </article>
 11. </section>
```

---

### CSS

```
 1.   section {
 2.       float: left;
 3.       width: 100%;
 4.   }
 5.   section article {
 6.       float: left;
 7.       width: 33.3%;
 8.       min-height: 100%;
 9.   }
```

---

The result i want is to get section to be expandable depending on articles height, without having to define a fixed height on the section.. But can't seem to get it to work. any suggestions?? :D

Answer (score 0):

Found a soultion for the problem: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/
in the middle of a schoolproject.. yeah..